# Is there a way to apply the shipping fee automatically?

Tags: expressionengine, expresso-store

Good day,

I have two shipping methods, which are "International Shipping" and "US Shipping".

Is there a way to apply the shipping fee without resubmitting it again after user fills in the billing/shipping address and process to the last phase of placing order ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this question recently and managed to figure it out.

```
$("#shipping_method").change(function(e) {
    $(this.form).submit();
});
```

[Asked and answered at EE Stack Exchange](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/19129/exp-resso-store-shipping-select-auto-refresh/19130#19130)